# Create /newcommand to make a table with line break

Tags: tables, macros, arguments

I am new to this forum, and LaTeX itself, so thank you in advance for the help. I'm trying to make a document with different drink recipes, where each drink has no more than four ingredients. I made a command where each time I want a new recipe, a table is made that holds the recipe for each drink. The problem comes when I try to list two recipes at a time. I either have to account for the optional arguments by adding empty rows, or manually add three line breaks within the TeX doc.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcommand{\recipe}[9]{\begin{tabular}{C{1cm} p{5cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{#1}} \\ \hline #2 & #3 \\ #4 & #5 \\ #6 & #7 \\ #8 & #9 \\ \end{tabular} \newline}
```

Which produces a single recipe when I use

```
    \recipe{White Russian}{3}{vodka}{2}{coffee liqueur}{3}{milk}
```

But when I put another recipe on the next line, say with only two ingredients, it creates an error.

Thanks again!

Comment: You allowed the input of a total of 9 mandatory arguments but your `\recipe` command only has 7 arguments. `\recipe{White Russian}{3}{vodka}{2}{coffee liqueur}{3}{milk}{}{}` instead should work. Notice the two sets of `{}` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I had tried that, and it does work.The problem I have with this method is that the output table then takes up the space for that "empty" line, when I only want the table to take up the space it needs. Is this condition possible with the command I've made?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting code fragments, its more helpful to turn the fragments into a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Oh, I see. Will do this in the future! Thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a macro to have a variable number of arguments, then the standard way to do this is to process the arguments as a delimited list. Since your ingredients come in pairs, you will also need a way to distinguish the amounts from the ingredients. Here I've used the `etoolbox` list processing macro `\forcsvlist` to process the list and created a simple delimited macro to distinguish the amounts from the ingredients. Using a delimited macro makes the input syntax a little simpler.

The `\recipe` macro now takes 2 arguments: the name and the list of ingredients.  Each ingredient is denoted with `\IN <amount>|<substance>`.

I'm sure there are other ways to do the same thing, and you're likely to have someone post a LaTeX3 solution too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\addrow}[1]{#1\\}
\def\IN#1|#2{#1 & #2}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\recipe}[2]{\begin{tabular}{C{1cm} p{5cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{#1}} \\ \forcsvlist\addrow{#2} \end{tabular} \par}
\begin{document}
\recipe{White Russian}{\IN 3|vodka,\IN 2|coffee liqueur,\IN 3|milk}

\recipe{Martini}{\IN 3|gin,\IN |vermouth}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I was looking for. I've simply added an \hline into the formatting. Thank you very much for your help!